# OAuth for Blogger

Tags: java, oauth, blogger

I have a desktop Java which access to my Blogger account. To authenticate with the Google Services, I just use the login and password system, which it is now disabled.

This is a short example on how I do that:

```
public void subePagina(String pagina) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, ServiceException {
        myEntry = new Entry();

        myEntry.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct(title_page));
        myEntry.setContent(new HtmlTextConstruct(page));
        myEntry.setDraft(false);

        activaServicio(); 

        URL editUrl = new URL("url_feed_entry);
        myService.update(editUrl, myEntry); 
}

public void activaServicio() throws AuthenticationException {
        myService = new GoogleService("blogger","blogname");
        myService.setUserCredentials(user, password);
}
```

I've tried to find a solution but I couldn't see enough information to do that, so, my question is, how can I do the same but ysing OAuth? I need to change more code than the activaServicio Method() ?

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried searching for Google Oauth2 java examples?  https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/oauth2?hl=en

Comment: Yes DalmTo, but there are no examples to access Blogger...

Comment: one you understand one api its easy enough to change it.   they are all the same really.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem, I'm not uinderstand how it works. Because of that I was asking for an example with Blogger to apply to my app...